# Outlook Web Access Password Expiry Notification - Default Settings

Tags: exchange, exchange-2013, outlook-web-app

Where can I find the default days of when Outlook Web Access will give me a password expiration notification.

Or is this directly related to the AD Policy that is in GPO

Thank you in advance for your time in answering this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OWA doesn't manage the password expiry - it has nothing to do with it. The password expiry notifications come from the AD settings. However if you have a heavy OWA use, then I would probably suggest you use a script to send users an email when their password is coming up for expiry instead.

Comment: When you say AD settings, you mean the gpo right?

Comment: Group Policy for the password expiry - which is part of Active Directory. Exchange has nothing to do with the management of the accounts.